# SELECT * behaving oddly - Swift SQLite FMDB

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

I have a TEST table that appears to be behaving just weird. It simply consists of two integers, ID (auto increment) and LOCATIONSELECTED.

The table is populated

```
1, 99
2, 100
3, 101
etc
```

If I try and find LOCATIONSELECTED using the code below it works and returns 99!

```
func getTestSelectedRecord() {
    sharedInstance.database!.open()
    var sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ID = 1"
    var resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery(sqlStatement, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    if (resultSet != nil) {
        while resultSet.next() {
            let getRecordID = resultSet.intForColumn("LOCATIONSELECTED")
            NSLog("DatabaseFunctions - TEST - GET - getRecordID = %i", getRecordID)
        }
    }
    sharedInstance.database!.close()
}
```

But if I remove the while loop it returns nul. I normally write my SELECT calls without the if != nil and while calls at all. There is only one record with an ID of 1 in the table.

I presume something subtle is going on here. Can anyone explain what it is?

Comment: You need call to resultSet.next() to get first result. U are removing it with the while clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the while loop, but you must maintain the:

```
resultSet.next();
```

statement, since is this the operation that allows to access the first (and only) record of the result.

Comment: So the original call doesn't take you to the first (and only) row? It's the resultSet.next() that points you there.

Comment: Yes, the original call only "prepares" the result to be read. It a "cursor", in database "jargon", so you have to "open" it in some way before using the records returned by the query.